# How to handle and event from pushing a physical button?

Tags: vb.net, circuit

Hello I am creating an application on vb.net which I want to launch an event whenever someone rings the doorbell. Can someone show me where I need to start looking? I know I need a circuit, but it should be very simple since I only want to push a button.
Thanks

Comment: This is a hardware question.  Wrong site.

Comment: @MartinJames you could have been more helpful and suggested where I should start looking as written in the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting hardware question. My solution here without additional hardware/circuit.

- Install Microsoft Speech SDK.
- Configure your MIC to listen to your doorbell.
- In your code, on distinguishing the doorbell, invoke a button click in your screen.  See below code to invoke a button:

  ```
  'Imports System.Windows.Automation.Peers
  'Imports System.Windows.Automation.Provider
  If SpeechObject(DetectDoorBellRing) = True Then
      Dim peer As New ButtonAutomationPeer(btnExecute)
      Dim invokeProv As IInvokeProvider = TryCast(peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke), IInvokeProvider)
      invokeProv.Invoke()
  End If
  ```

Answer (score 1):

[Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) is a open-source hardware and supporting software project that you should be aware of.  It's typically programmed in C or C++, but see "[How to Communicate to the Arduino in Visual Basic .NET](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14194.how-to-communicate-to-the-arduino-in-visual-basic-net.aspx)".

You might also pick up some good ideas from "[How to Hack a Doorbell and Connect it to Twitter](http://blog.crutzen.eu/2013/07/16/how-to-hack-a-doorbell-and-connect-it-to-twitter-part-1-introduction/)".

Finally, don't miss the [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).